# Laravel eloquent - how to use DB raw inside custom relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have laravel models :
Post and Comment. As normal, post will have many comment 
tables as bellow:

```
Posts table
--------------------------------------
|id   |title   |                     |
--------------------------------------
|1    |test    |

comments table: 
--------------------------------------
|id   |post_id |   created_at       |
--------------------------------------
|1    |1          |2015-09-12 09:01:02 |    
--------------------------------------
|2    |1          |2015-09-12 09:03:02 |
```

now I want to query for the post with the most number of comments from current date back to last 7 days. 
Here is my code in Laravel Controller:

```
$posts= Post::whereHas(
         'comments', function ($q) {
             $q->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')"),'post_id',DB::raw('count(*) as cmt_count'))
             ->where(DB::raw('`comments`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 8 DAY AND NOW()'))
                 ->groupBy('post_id');

         })
         ->take(5)->get();
```

got the ERROR:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 651: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 3 column(s) (SQL: select * from `posts` where (select DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), `post_id`, count(*) as cmt_count from `comments` where `comments`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` and `comments`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 8 DAY AND NOW() is null group by `post_id`) >= 1 limit 5)
```

Please help to point me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

OK. after some digging with the suggestions above, I have solved the problem myself.
Post this answer here for anyone who having the same problem could find it useful.
bellow is the query (assumed you already set up the relationship )

```
$posts = Post::select(DB::raw('posts.id,posts.title,count(*) as cmnt_count'))
->join('comments',function($q){
  $q->on('posts.id','=','comments.post_id')
     ->where(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(comments.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))",'>=',Carbon::now()->subDays(7));
})->groupBy('posts.id')
->orderBy('cmnt_count')->get();
```

now I can get what I want: retrieve all posts which have comments within 7 days and sort by the number of comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the whole logic of your SQL. But the problem is with the following part:

```
`comments`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 8 DAY AND NOW() is null
```

Now the part of your query builder responsive for this piece is:

```
where(DB::raw('`comments`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 8 DAY AND NOW()'))
```

This is quite clear - you want to use a raw where expression. but where method usually takes 2 or three params.

Why don't you try replacing it with whereRaw?

Your builder would look like this:

```
$posts= Post::whereHas(
         'comments', function ($q) {
             $q->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')"),'post_id',DB::raw('count(*) as cmt_count'))
             ->whereRaw('`comments`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 8 DAY AND NOW()')
                 ->groupBy('post_id');

         })
         ->take(5)->get();
```

This should use the whereRaw argument as a raw piece of the final SQL.

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Take care

Comment: thank for your response, but your query not work as expect . Bellow is error response from laravel :` QueryException in Connection.php line 651: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 3 column(s) (SQL: select * from posts where (select DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), post_id, count(*) as cmt_count from comments where comments.post_id = post.id and comments.created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 8 DAY AND NOW() group by post_id) >= 1 limit 5)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$q->select()`, `whereHas()` expecting the query to return a number (typically count(*)).
The `whereHas()` is likely to select parent records where the count of its relative records is more than 1.

Try `->toSql()` instead of `->take(5)->get()` to see your raw SQL query.

**====== EDIT ========**

I think you could do something like this.

```
$posts= Post::whereHas(
     'comments', function ($q) {
         $q->where(DB::raw('`comments`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 8 DAY AND NOW()'))
             ->groupBy('post_id');

     })
     ->with('comment_counts') 
     ->take(5)->get();
```

Or if you want to use *Carbon*:

```
$q->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->addWeek(-1))
```

In your model:

```
class Post extends Model {
//...
     public function comment_counts() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Comment')->select([ DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')"),'post_id',DB::raw('count(*) as cmt_count') ]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can have Laravel to return me the raw query using DB::getQueryLog()

Comment: You would see that `whereHas` would transform into a sub-query `... AND (SELECT .... FROM <table> WHERE ...) >= 1 ...` that's why when you put `->select()` that return more than 1 fields, it throws an SQL error. It's not a problem about `DB::raw()` but rather SQL query error. And if the code runs fine, it would not return a 'count' or 'created_at' for you, since you SELECT count(*) within a subquery, not in the 'posts' query itself.

Comment: So. Do you have any suggest to accomplish what I need as stated in my question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, I haven't try but it must work

```
$posts= Post::whereHas(
         'comments', function ($q) {
             $q->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')"),'post_id',DB::raw('count(*) as cmt_count'))
             ->groupBy('post_id')
             ->where('created_at','>',DB::raw('date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)'))
             ->where(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'),'<=',DB::raw('CURDATE()'));

         })
         ->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: your solution is not different from these above answers and comments. not gonna work.